# Move an ssas cube from one analysis services database to another

Tags: ssas

I have an analysis services database which consists of more than 8 cubes. From that, I want one single cube to be moved in to another analysis services database (this database should have only that cube). Instead of doing all the cube work from scratch, is there a easy way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this would be to just copy all files of your BIDS project to a new folder. Then open the new project in BIDS, delete all dimensions and cubes not needed, change the deployment target, and redeploy.